# How to split a variable into an array in batch

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I'm trying to write a text adventure in batch, so I want to know how I can split variable like set userinput=take book and turn it into an array. I want to be able to write a program that will split strings into array items at each space. I've done this in a lot of other languages. There are several other questions like this, but I don't feel like they answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This task is probably much more difficult than you realize. There are lots of "simple" methods, but none of the simple ones are robust.

For example, a simple FOR loop can parse out individual tokens, but it will be broken by `*`, `?`, and possibly `"`.

A robust solution requires a significant amount of code.

Here is my solution, with extensive comments:

```
@echo off

:: Start out with delayed expansion disabled, and define "user input"
:: I intentionally include "problem" characters
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "userinput=take book! & ;MustPreserve    EmptyLinesAreIgnored"

:: Initialize count
set "cnt=0"

:: Enable and use delayed expansion to protect against poison characters
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Substitute <LineFeed> for each <space>
(set parsed=!userinput: =^
%= Do not remove or alter this line =%
!)

:: Iterate each line, setting delims and eol to <space> to preserve all tokens
for /f "eol= delims= " %%A in ("!parsed!") do (

  %= Return to delayed expansion disabled on first iteration, else ! is lost =%
  if "!" equ "" endlocal

  %= Increment the count =%
  set /a cnt+=1

  %= Temporarily enable delayed expansion to capture current count in FOR variable =%
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%N in (!cnt!) do (
    endlocal

    %= Save the array value =%
    set "token.%%N=%%A"
  )
)

::Print the results. Safe array access requires delayed expansion
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 !cnt!) do echo token.%%N=!token.%%N!
```

It looks a bit better without all the comments

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "userinput=take book! & :MustPreserveColon ;MustPreserve    EmptyLinesAreIgnored"

set "cnt=0"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(set parsed=!userinput: =^
%= Do not remove or alter this line =%
!)
for /f "eol= delims= " %%A in ("!parsed!") do (
  if "!" equ "" endlocal
  set /a cnt+=1
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for %%N in (!cnt!) do (
    endlocal
    set "token.%%N=%%A"
  )
)

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 !cnt!) do echo token.%%N=!token.%%N!
```

And here is the output:

```
token.1=take
token.2=book!
token.3=&
token.4=;MustPreserve
token.5=EmptyLinesAreIgnored
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        @echo off
        color 08 & Title %~dpnx0
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo.______S__T__A__R__T_______


echo.                       ArrayNumber:   HierarchieChange inside of the for 
echo.                           or     start lenght with 1
echo.   ArrayPosi Zero is not defined in this example       


set array[4]=you


set array=one two

set array=!array! three


set /a lenght=0 
 for %%a in (!array!) do (
    set array[!lenght!]=%%a
    set /a lenght+=1
 )


echo.___!array[2]!___!array[1]!___!array[0]!

                        echo.&echo.
                        echo.******************************************

for /l %%a in (!lenght!,-1, -1) do echo !array[%%a]!

                        echo._______________________________________________

for /l %%a in (0,1,!lenght!) do echo !array[%%a]!

echo.&echo.____________without any errors____________________
set /a lenght-=1
for /l %%a in (0,1,!lenght!) do echo !array[%%a]!


echo.-----------------------------------------------------
echo.-----------------------------------------------------
echo. but the charPos 1 is zero when u splitt Strings

set splitt=ABCD

echo !splitt!>TSCHHHHHHHHHHUUUUUUUUUUUUUNGBamBam.txt

for %%a in (TSCHHHHHHHHHHUUUUUUUUUUUUUNGBamBam.txt) do set /a chars=%%~za -2

echo. chars:    !chars!

echo. char3:    !splitt:~2,1!



for /l %%a in (0,1,!chars!) do echo.  %%a !splitt:~%%a,1!



        echo._________E__N__D__________
        timeout 3 >nul
pause
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining your answer, and ideally, comment your code. The currently accepted answer from @dbenham is a good model.